# How to paginate a large amount of data using Java/sql/html?

Tags: java, html, pagination

I created a web application using Java for backend and html/jquery for frontend.
In the backend, I have a method that extracts a very large amount of data from sql (3000000 rows) and I need to place these rows in a html table.
I would like to paginate these rows

Does anybody have any idea how to do that?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass two parameters pageSize and pageNumber to each Java call.
pageSize and pageNumber  need to be maintained in UI(javascript/jquery). pagesize can be a dropdown or a fixed number say 25 and pageNumber the number of page user is viewing  and is usually  a number assigned to button or link the user selects.
On database query that gets called from Java you need to write query that fetches records with pageSize  from pageNumber something like:

`select * from data_table limit :pageSize offset :pageNumber 
select * from data_table limit 25 offset 1`

Comment: **More Importantly** Are you planning to allow users to request "3,000,000" rows - any old time they want?  Or are you just trying to generate output ".html" files that are paginated and saved to disk - _so they may be statically returned_ as `page0x.html` files?